# Using host file

Tags: dns, host-header, javascript, security

I created an application in SharePoint, lets call it http://example.com/ and a site collection with the "Empty Site" template.

Since I'm using it locally in a **virtual machine in host-only mode**, I had to edit my **host file** to add

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

Now, whenever I access this website, I cannot click on "Site Action". All it does is add a `#` at the end of the URL.

Since I'm in a host-only VM, i cannot change the DNS to make it work (that's the way we fixed it for a dev server).

Comment: Sorry for the DNS tag, I didn't found anything else and cannot create new ones (like `host-file`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript might be disabled

Try adding example.com to your trusted sites in IE to allow javascript to run on pages within example.com

Comment: Cannot upvote since I don't have enough rep. Very good catch. Thank you.

Comment: Upvoted for dex.